# How To Get mySql query results from another query

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have 3 mySql table:

```
shop
        id1  shop_name 
         1   shop1
         2   shop2
         3   shop3

    queue_number
        id2  id_shop  queue_current_number
         1      1             32
         2      2             56
         3      3             22

    queue_customer
        id3  id_queue   your_number   
         1      1            33
         2      1            34
         3      1            35
         4      2            57
```

I'm starting with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop
LEFT JOIN queue_number ON queue_number.id_shop = shop.id1
WHERE id_shop = 1
GROUP BY id2
```

**My Results:**

shop1 > queue_current_number = 32

shop2 > queue_current_number = 56

shop3 > queue_current_number = 22

**I'd like to get a result like this:**

shop1 > queue_current_number = 35

shop2 > queue_current_number = 57

shop3 > queue_current_number = 22

Thanks!

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And will 'your_number' always be higher than 'queue_current_number' - or do you always want to return 'your_number', if available, regardless?

Comment: I'd like get higher number from 'your_number' if exist else get 'queue_current_number'

Comment: So when preparing the MCVE, perhaps amend the data set to make that clearer.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the point of id2 on the queue number table. (I don't really understand the point of id3 on the queue_customer table either)

Comment: id1, id2 and id3 are autoincrement id

Answer (score 0):

Try this with subquery:

```
SELECT shop.id1, shop.name, COALESCE(younumber,queue_current_number) as q_current_number
FROM shop
LEFT JOIN queue_number ON queue_number.id_shop = shop.id1
left join
(select id_queue,max(your_number) as younumber
from queue_customer group by id_queue)c on c.id_queue= shop.id1
WHERE id_shop = 1
```

Comment: Have this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as queue_current_number
FROM shop
LEFT JOIN queue_number ON queue_number.id_shop' at line 1

Comment: modified the query, mistakenly i put tablename as column

Comment: Tried with this query but the result is the same as before

Comment: Result is: shop1 > queue_current_number = 32

shop2 > queue_current_number = 56 - 

shop3 > queue_current_number = 22

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for the highest value, either by preferring queue_customer over queue_number (use COALESCE...), or by wanting the highest maximum of the two (use IF(COALESCE...).

```
    SELECT COALESCE( c.your_number, n.queue_current_number ) 
    /* or maybe you want IF( COALESCE( c.your_number, 0 ) > COALESCE( n.queue_current_number, 0 ), c.your_number, n.queue_current_number ) */
    FROM shop s
    LEFT JOIN queue_number n   ON s.id1 = n.id_shop 
                              AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM queue_number n2
                                              WHERE n.id_shop = n2.id_shop
                                                AND n.queue_current_number < n2.queue_current_number )
    LEFT JOIN queue_customer c ON n.id2 = c.id_queue
                              AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM current_number c2
                                              WHERE c.id_queue = c2.id_queue
                                                AND n.your_number < n2.your_number )
    WHERE s.id_shop = 1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but have this error > Table 'my_table.current_number' doesn't exist

Comment: I don't see my_table.current_number anywhere in the query, but a guess could be that I used alias and then you have to use the alias everywhere. So when you have FROM shop s, then you have to use s.id1 and never shop.id1